# Determine if a value exists between two time points in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe `blinded_SMBG_DF` with glucose values `blinded_SMBG_DF.Glucose` and timestamps as `index`. I need a piece of code that will check if there is an entry between two timestamps and if so report "yes" and if not report "no".

I tried the following:

```
if 0.1 <= blinded_SMBG_DF.Glucose.loc['2021-01-08 08:30:00' : '2021-01-08 09:00:00'][0] <= 100:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

and it works when there is a value in that range and prints "yes" but reports an error if there is no value in the df with that value. How do I change it so that instead of reporting an error it just reports "no" or NaN or something similar?

Thanks so much.

Comment: are you looking for [pandas.Series.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between_time.html)?

Comment: Sort of but I don't want to find the values between the time points I just want to know if one exists. The problem with .between_time is that if the value doesn't exist you get an error. I essentially just need a boolean of whether there is a value or not between those points. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use .count()

```
    if df.Glucose.loc[start : end].count() >= 1:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```